# gcc warning "does not declare anything

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm working on updating some C++ code to C+11 by converting typedef's into using aliases. Given the following SCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <linux/cn_proc.h>
/**
 * Legacy C structure
 */
struct sample {
  enum what {
    FOO,
    BAR
  } what;
};

void tdef( ) {
    typedef enum sample::what demo;
    demo a = sample::FOO;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

void usingdemo( ) {
    using demo = enum sample::what;
    demo a = sample::BAR;
    std::cout << a
    << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    tdef();
    usingdemo();
}
```

I'm getting a warning using the using declaration:

```
warning: declaration ‘enum sample::what’ does not declare anything
     using demo = enum sample::what;
                               ^
```

although the code compiles and executes fine. Compiler is *g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609* Does the fault lie in the compiler, or in me?

---

Thanks for the replies. In regards to the comments about the C struct:

- The "S" is SCCE is small, so I posted the smallest struct that would
  demonstrate the issue. The actual struct I'm using is "struct proc_event" from
  [linux/cn_proc.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/cn_proc.h).
- I'm just including it without the "extern C"
  and it's working fine.

Comment: Does anything change if you remove `enum`?

Comment: @melpomene - yes it will - a different error, not a warning.

Comment: @melpomene yup. It rejects code saying `what` is not a struct. FWIW clang and icc do not complain about anything in OPs code. It might be incorrect diagnostic in gcc.

Comment: @luk32 Neither does VC++ with /W4

Comment: Did you try `using demo = typename sample::what;'? It is a nested type, after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the fault lie in the compiler?

This is a compiler bug. It appears to have been reported already: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66159 . The problem reproduces when an elaborated name specifier is used in a using declaration. In this case, you need to use elaborated name specifier to avoid ambiguity with the member that has the same name.

Workaround: Use `typedef` declaration instead:

```
typedef enum sample::what demo;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have created both a type `sample::what` and a member `sample::what`.  The compiler should, and apparently does resolve this and the warning is benign and apparently erroneous.

The problem goes away with:

```
struct sample {
  enum what {
    FOO,
    BAR
  } what_instance;  //  << Different identifier here
};
```

and:

```
using demo = sample::what;
```

Having a type identifier and an instance identifier with the same name is a bad idea in any case for a number of reasons.  It is confusing to humans, and in this case the compiler also. Perhaps the compiler is trying to tell you something ;-)

Comment: True, but OP did not declare that enum and likely cannot change that: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/cn_proc.h#L47. It seems to be a part of a Linux header file.

Comment: @DanielLangr, well that is clearly C code and this is C++, so the struct should have an `extern "C"` declaration if it refers to the same thing.  Not that solves the problem either.  What can you say about the coding standards in Linux!?

Comment: Nothing, but I would consider this a very bad coding practice (to name an enum/struct/class the same as its instance). Surprises me it's in a Linux header.

Comment: @Clifford I don't think `extern "C"` is needed for struct definitions - it's needed for functions and global variables.

Comment: @eerorika It definitely does, but it is not relevant to this question, just an observation. The compiler will name mangle it and it will not resolve to the same symbol as in the C code.  In C++ a struct is a variant of a class.

Comment: @Clifford Sorry to stay off topic from the question: I checked the standard: `language linkage applies to the function types of all function declarators, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage` It appears to not apply to structs, enums or members.

Comment: @eerorika but structs in C++ can have member functions.

Comment: @Clifford Correct. But that's irrelevant to whether `extern "C"` is needed.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply define demo type to int because enum can be converted to a temporary int

```
void usingdemo( ) {
  using demo = int;
  ...
}
```